# (Django, Python) How do I fix json.decoder.JSONDecodeError?

Tags: python, json, django

I have been trying to make an order/cart app for a sandwich shop. While I am testing I keep getting the error that has to do with decoding the JSON data front-end engineers send me.

Below is the POST request that the server receives.

```
{
    "default_ingredients": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "이탈리안 화이트 (top)",
            "image_url": "https://media.subway.com/digital/Account_Updates/Assets/App-Base/Web_Images/Subway/en-us/Options/o_BreadItalian_customizer_large.png",
            "price": "0.00",
            "ingredient_category_id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 23,
            "name": "토마토",
            "image_url": "https://media.subway.com/digital/Account_Updates/Assets/App-Base/Web_Images/Subway/en-us/OptionsIds/10133_customizer_large.png",
            "price": "0.00",
            "ingredient_category_id": 3
        },
    ],
    "added_ingredients": [
        {
            "id": 18,
            "name": "살라미",
            "image_url": "https://media.subway.com/digital/Account_Updates/Assets/App-Base/Web_Images/Subway/en-us/Options/o_TurkeyBasedHamSalamiBologna_customizer_large.png",
            "price": "0.00",
            "ingredient_category_id": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 19,
            "name": "페퍼로니",
            "image_url": "https://media.subway.com/digital/Account_Updates/Assets/App-Base/Web_Images/Subway/en-us/Options/o_Pepperoni_customizer_large.png",
            "price": "1800.00",
            "ingredient_category_id": 2
        },
    ],
    "product_name": "이탈리안 비엠티",
}
```

And below is my views.py for the order app

```
import json
import ast
import jwt
import bcrypt

from django.views               import View
from django.http                import JsonResponse

from .models        import (
    Order, 
    Cart, 
    CartIngredient, 
    DestinationLocation, 
    OrderStatus
) 
from product.models import (
    Product, 
    Category, 
    SubCategory, 
    Nutrition, 
    Ingredient, 
    ProductIngredient
)
from store.models           import Store
from account.models         import Customer
from codesandwich.settings  import SECRET_KEY

def login_required(func):
        def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            
            header_token    = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
            decoded_token   = jwt.decode(header_token, SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')['email']
            
            try:
                if Customer.objects.filter(email=decoded_token).exists():
                    return func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({"message": "customer does not exist"})
            except jwt.DecodeError:
                return JsonResponse({"message": "WRONG_TOKEN!"}, status=403)
            except KeyError:
                return JsonResponse({"message": "Key Error"}, status=405)
            except Customer.objects.filter(email=decoded_token).DoesNotExist:
                return JsonResponse({"message": "User Not Found"}, status=406)
        return wrapper

class CartView(View):

    @login_required
    def post(self, request):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
######### PART THAT NEEDS TO BE FIXED ################################
        body = json.loads(request.body).decode('utf-8')             #
######################################################################        
        ## must receive user info
        ## decoded_token -> email -> filter(email=email) -> retrieve id
        header_token    = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', '')
        decoded_token   = jwt.decode(header_token,SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')['email']
        customer_id = Customer.objects.get(email=decoded_token).id
        a = Customer.objects.get(id=customer_id)
         ## below is when the customer's order is still active 
        if Order.objects.filter(customer_id = customer_id).last().order_status.id == 2:
            
            ## update the order by just adding carts
            order_id = Order.objects.filter(customer = a).last().id
            order = Order.objects.get(id = order_id)
            if body['product']:
                product_id = body['product']['id']
                product = Product.objects.get(id = product_id)
                #this extracts the price
                price = body['product']['default_price']
                price = float(price)
                ## make a new cart for default_item
                Cart.objects.create(order = order, price = price, amount = 1, product = product)
                order.total_price += price
                order.save()
```

The part in question is right below 'class CartView(View)'

And this is the error message:

```
> /Users/woohyunan/projects/Wecode/code-sandwich/code-sandwich-backend/code-sandwich-backend/order/views.py(52)post()->None
-> body = json.loads(request.body).decode('utf-8')
(Pdb) next
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 17 column 2 (char 636)
> /Users/woohyunan/projects/Wecode/code-sandwich/code-sandwich-backend/code-sandwich-backend/order/views.py(36)wrapper()
-> return func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

What should I do to avoid this error? I have tried ast as well but it still didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The answer was in decoding with 'utf-8' BEFORE using the ast evaluation.

```
body = ast.literal_eval(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
```